# TeXShop and OSX10.12.6

Tags: accents

Why TeXShop won't let me use accented letter as "è" if I use in the preamble the suggested 
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
 `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.
I'm currently using OS X 10.12.6. I have downloaded TeXmaker and it works there, but I want to use TeXShop.
This is the message I receive

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char è\endabstract (U+4E
F)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

...

I've read about 
    `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` but it create a mess with most of the text.

Comment: What encoding was used to save the original file. TeXShop out of the box saves files in latin9 encoding. Definitely don't use applemac. See the Help->File Encoding and TeXShop document for a bit more information.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Why? I know it does, but I was really shocked when I discovered this. It seems really perverse that it defaults to anything other than UTF8.

Comment: @cfr : the article actually discusses that. For the most part it's because beginners get very confused when presented with error messages when opening a file. Also, there are many folks in Western Europe that use latin1 or latin9 (for the most part identical). Eastern European, Middle Eastern and Asian Languages basically use specialized encodings. Even Unicode, which tries to unite everything, has multiple ways of storing data although UTF-8 seems to be most popular and ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. PS: I use UTF-8 and it's easy to set that as the default in TeXShop.

Comment: @HerbSchulz The thing is, it makes it very likely they will get such error messages if, for example, trying to migrate from one of the online services to a local installation or trying to follow instructions for first-time users of editors (generically) or trying to open files produced using default settings in most other editors. Being the odd one out greatly increases the chances users will see error messages when opening, compiling etc.

Comment: @HerbSchulz In multiple workshops, with students using a mix of OverLeaf, ShareLaTeX and laptops with various editors, the only encoding problem I've had was a student using the default editor provided for Macs. It took me a considerable time to figure the problem out. (In the meantime, we got another, working editor installed.) And I used to use TeXShop myself. Yes, it is easy to change the default. But you have to figure out that's the flipping problem first. On their own, I'm sure the student would have simply abandoned TS for good as the OverLeaf code worked in everything else.

Comment: @cfr : Do those other Editors all use UTF-8 encoding as default or do they use heuristics to determine the encoding of the file? While UTF-8 encoding is getting more common there are huge numbers of documents produced with latin1/9 and other encodings. What happens when the students try to collaborate with others that use another encoding. The wise thing is to always have the TeXShop encoding declaration at the top of the file in any templates you use so TeXShop, and other Editors that understand it, will open the file with the correct encoding.

Comment: @HerbSchulz They're defaulting to UTF8 mostly, I think. I don't know if they are also trying to detect the encoding. Certainly OverLeaf etc. default to UTF8 for new documents. And they are the basis of the documents the students are creating and then opening in local editors.